# If I use React components from Material UI, is it possible to add custom functionality on top of them?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is more of a general question, as I don't have any specific code examples yet. I'd like to know if this is possible before starting to use it.

So as an example, let's say I want to use MaterialUI's Table components rather than make it from scratch, but I want to add the ability to use hotkeys for selecting rows (or any other functionality that isn't inherently available from the imported components), is this a realistic use-case? Or should I instead endeavor to create the components from scratch if I want extra functionality?

Comment: It depends specifically on what you're trying to do with which components and how. Hotkeys, in general, are a completely separate topic, and can be handled in a wide variety of ways--whether or not you'd be able to do what you want depends on specifics.

Comment: Thanks for the input, @DaveNewton. Yeah, I feared that my question would be too broad as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

If the component itself doesn't offer the functionality out of the box, you won't be able to add it yourself.

This isn't a hard rule, as for example, some components don't specifically implement an `onClick` prop, but instead, they pass all the props along, so if you send `onClick` it will still work. This is mostly the case for simple component, let's say a "button".

However with complex components such as a `Table`, if you want an `onClick` for a row, and the component doesn't give you a prop or some way to access it, then you're out of luck.

Something you can consider if copying their source code, which is open source, and implementing your own extra functionality :) Consider opening a PR for it if you think it's a good thing to add to the library.

Comment: Ah, of course. The idea that I can only pass props that the components are made to readily accept will make it possible for me to inspect the source code for the components, and evaluate each specific use-case. I will check it out, thanks!